# Doesn't attaching ng-click within a template defeat the purpose of MV*?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, event-handling, angularjs

In angularjs there are examples where the ng-click handler is attached directly to an html element such as `<a>` or `<button>`. See my example below (taken from an angular home page example). It defines the anchor tag's click handler, which will call `archive()`.

Doesn't this go against the whole MV* framework? Wouldn't it be better to define the click somewhere other than the view? It just seems like a bit too much functionality is now attached to the anchor tag. Can anyone enlighten me here?

Example Code:

```
<a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a>
```

Comment: I don't think that (essentially) specifying JS-routes in HTML has something to do with separation of business and representation logic (the key point of MV* patterns). After all, does specifying _links_ in HTML (that something that should go in 'href' attribute here) defeats the purpose of MVC? And it's the same, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do have to attach commands / behaviours somewhere and I think Angular's approach to do it declaratively in the view is much nicer than doing in imperatively in JS files with DOM selectors which will silently break as soon as you change your markup structure / naming.

This is what Microsoft's XAML / C# MVVM framework does too and the separation of concerns is beautiful there, I'm really hoping Angular is going to go towards that model where it's possible to encapsulate and attach view only behaviours purely in markup.